# What does this sentence imply, as worded, in terms of the amount of Caucasians, e.g. some, all or another amount of Caucasians?

Tags: meaning, american-english

"Next time Caucasians might think about voting with facts and common sense instead of with their white guilt."

Comment: What do you think it means? (This is not a rhetorical question. By showing your currently level of understanding, you allow answers to be targeted to whatever specific confusion you have.) See also [Wikipedia on *white guilt*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_guilt).

Comment: This follows in the original: [Sue4477  Stargazerlily17](http://teapartypolitics.com/obama-sued-republicans-pulling-trigger/) 
'RACISM LIVES ON! Show me the facts that prove all Caucasians, as you implicate, voted for [O]bama (and possibly others of color) out of white guilt. You won't find them because it's not true. Maybe you should use 'common sense' and research and 'thinking twice' yourself before making such prejudicial statements. Criticizing 'those Caucasians who voted for [O]bama out of white guilt' would have been more accurate.' But I'm not getting involved in US politics.

Comment: It's not really possible to explain what it means without getting into the rhetoric of extreme politics in the US.  It's a different language which just happens to use the same words as English.

Comment: I changed the question to be more specific. As previously worded, it didn't accurately address my question in understanding the meaning of "Caucasians" as used in this sentence. It is my 1st post and I apologize for the poor wording of my question.

Comment: In this sort of rhetoric "Caucasians" could mean 5 of them, or millions.  If the speaker can actually point to even one that in fact did express "white guilt" he will imply that that generalizes to the entirety of Caucasians nationwide.

Answer (score 1):

I inferred that that speaker believes that the subject Caucasian voters did not vote for the most logically appealing candidate, but instead applied emotions borne out of some supposed guilt that they bear, specific to white people.

Other people may infer other, and potentially more specific, meanings and without context it is impossible to know what the speaker was intending to imply.

Answer (score 1):

The speaker is implying that (in his/her opinion) Caucasians failed to vote for what he/she perceives to have been the best candidate (based on "facts" and "common sense" as the speaker understands them). Rather, the speaker is asserting that they were led to vote irrationally/illogically for someone else because of guilt associated with their race (you can read more about "White guilt" and "White privilege" elsewhere).

This is a personal observation and not strictly germane to your question, but in my honest opinion, this sort of rhetoric is most commonly spewed by "nationalistic" politicians who try to wrap up their virulently racist views in euphemistic verbiage (like this). I normally prefer to remain dispassionate in my answers, but I thought it was important I included a candid assessment of the likely context because it's useful in understanding the motives of the speaker.